# Use jQuery zoom on background image Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

The code works exactly as I'm looking for, I just want to know why it doesn't work on the woocommerce "single-product" page.

When I ran jQuery, it was added as a style when I hovered over the `img` but I found it was not functional.

I'm wondering if I need to do anything else in Woocommerce. I searched but couldn't find any results.

```js
$('.wp-post-image').mousemove(function(e) {
  var amountMovedX = (e.pageX * -1 / 2);
  var amountMovedY = (e.pageY * -1 / 2);
  $(this).css({
    'background-size': '200%',
    'background-position': amountMovedX + 'px ' + amountMovedY + 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
.wp-post-image {
  background-image: url('https://www.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/tnl_redesign_article_landing_page/public/1453920892/DUBAI-554088081-ABOVE0116.jpg?itok=dcoZnCrc');
  background-size: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wp-post-image"></div>
```

Comment: 'It doesn't work' is far too broad a description for anyone to help you. Can you provide an example displaying the problem, and check the console for errors.

Comment: it seems ok, no "console" error either but I can't enlarge the photo.
I wish I could help you out if I could figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the solution I'm looking for, what I'm looking for is exactly as in this link: [magnifier](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-custom-image-magnifier-using-jquery/)
Woocommerce must have a setting, it's blocking it, I just couldn't find it

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if I need to do anything else in Woocommerce

Well, if this is a custom script, then you should first `enqueue` jquery onto your page.

The following code goes into the `functions.php` file of your theme.

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_them_adding_jquery');

function your_them_adding_jquery()
{
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

OR

You could `enqueue` your custom script and load jquery as its dependency. For example, you could save your snippet to a file called "your_custom_zoom.js" and use the following snippet to load it into the woocommerce:

The following code goes into the `functions.php` file of your theme.

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_them_adding_custom_zoom');

function your_them_adding_custom_zoom()
{
  wp_enqueue_script('custom-zoom', get_theme_file_uri('/js/your_custom_zoom.js'), 'JQuery', 1.5, TRUE);
}
```

Note:
The file path to your custom javascript file could be different. In this example, I created a folder called `js` in the theme root folder and saved my javascript file in it.

Also note, if you want to use jquery `$` in wordpress, you need to use your code like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready($ => {

  $('.wp-post-image').mousemove(function (e) {
    var amountMovedX = (e.pageX * -1 / 2);
    var amountMovedY = (e.pageY * -1 / 2);
    $(this).css({
      'background-size': '200%',
      'background-position': amountMovedX + 'px ' + amountMovedY + 'px'
    });
  });

});
```

---

However, woocommerce offers its own `gallery zoom` feature. If you want to use it then you need to add it to your theme.

The following code goes into the `functions.php` file of your theme.

```php
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'your_theme_support_for_woo_zoom');

function your_theme_support_for_woo_zoom()
{
  add_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-zoom');
  add_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-lightbox');
  add_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-slider');
};
```